# Troubles with executing script in custom post type archive page

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, custom-post-type, genesis

I have a custom post type archive page where I'd like to execute a specific script for the page. The script is loaded in the page with this function (in function.php):

```
function cpt_archive_enqueue_script() {
 if (is_post_type_archive('cpt-slug')) {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'cpt-archive-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/cpt-archive-script.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );
  };
}

add_action ('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'cpt_archive_enqueue_script');
```

As I can see with page inspector, the page loads the script but the loaded script is not executed ( the same script work f.e. if loaded in a category page).

Have anyone a suggestion to fix this? Thanks!

If can help here is the loaded script (it is a really simple script that opens the article content if the title is clicked).

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

 $('article.post').each(function() {
   var $dropdown = $(this);

   $("div.entry-title", $dropdown).click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $div = $("div.entry-content", $dropdown);
     $div.toggle();
     $("div.entry-content").not($div).hide();
     return false;
   });

});

 $('html').click(function(){
   $("div.entry-content").hide();
 });

});
```

Comment: are you using child theme?

Comment: yes, the site use genesis as framework and sample child theme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with below code it must be work on each page.

```
add_action('wp_head','callfunctioneverywhere');
function callfunctioneverywhere()
{
  echo '<script defer src="'.get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/js/cpt-archive-script.js" ></script>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it still doesn't work, you changed the name of the script and removed the version, right? Or I miss something?

Comment: unfortunately not for custom post type archive, without if condition works only for category archives or posts…

Comment: what is your post type can you clear me again i am getting confused here and on which page you wish to display single.php archive.ph or where?

Comment: Thanks for your time, maybe the terms I used are confusing, I try to clarify it. 
Suppose that the custom post type slug is 'portfolio'. I have the cpt archive page 'archive-portfolio.php' . in 'function.php' I have inserted the function above to load the code just only in page  'archive-portfolio.php'

Comment: Now please check if it did not work than i am having another solution as well but today any how we will resolve this issue

Comment: not works, sadly, now site crashes. I'm also thinking about it could be a problem on the script, but classes and page structure for the category archive and for CPT archive are identical

Comment: show me html please now the issue can be with html or jquery only

Comment: Ok, your new code works in the sense that the script is loaded on every page of the site but, in the cpt archive page the script is loaded but it is not executed (in other pages works perfectly)

Comment: I guess it will not ger the .post  class. Finally we got solution

Comment: But if I delete the second line of the script it does not execute yet while it continues to work on other pages ...

Comment: Yes because post class was coming in all other pages.. you need to check with firebug on not working page

Comment: Finally we did it mark as a correct answer and do upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the whole code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $('article.post').each(function() {
    var $dropdown = $(this);

    $("div.entry-title", $dropdown).click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $div = $("div.entry-content", $dropdown);
      $div.toggle("blind", 300);
      $("div.entry-content").not($div).hide("blind", { direction: "up" }, "300");
      return false;
    });

});

  $('html').click(function(){
    $("div.entry-content").hide("blind", { direction: "up" }, "300");
  });

});
```

```css
.hide {display: none;}
```

```html
<?php

//* add custom classes 
add_filter( 'body_class', 'journal' );
function journal ( $classes ) {

 $classes[] = 'journal';
 return $classes;

}

//* Remove the link from each post title
 add_filter( 'genesis_post_title_output', 'elimina_link_titolo', 15 );
  function elimina_link_titolo( $title ) {
         $title = sprintf( '<div class="entry-title five-sixth mostra">%s</div> ', apply_filters( 'genesis_post_title_text', get_the_title() ) );
   return $title;
  }

//* Add the 'hide' class ( .hide {display: none;} )to not show the content that will appear by clicking on title
add_filter ('genesis_attr_entry-content', '\margine_sx_un_terzo');
 function margine_sx_un_terzo ( array $attributes ) {
  $attributes['class'] .= ' hide';

  return $attributes;
 }

genesis();
```